# Unable to get the correct context with bind() using a promise

Tags: javascript, ajax, oop, requirejs, promise

I'm unable to get the correct context in one of my inner functions using `bind()`. Here is my code:

```
return {
    /**
     * Checks if the table loader is active
     * @return {home} Returns this module for chaining
     */
    loadStatusLog: function() {
        if ($("#status-log-box").length) {
            $.getJSON("/Home/CurrentEvents", function(json, status, xhr) {
                if (status === "error") {
                    var errmsg = "Sorry but there was an error: ";
                    $("#result-msg").html(errmsg + xhr.status + " " + xhr.statusText);
                }
                else if (status === "success") {
                    if (json.globalGenerationStatus) {
                        console.log(this);
                        this.updateProgressInterval = setInterval(this.updateGenerationProgress, 1000);
                    }
                    var html = statusLog(json);
                    $("#status-log-table").html(html);
                }
            }.bind(this));
        }
        return this;
    },
    /**
     * Looks at the generation progress file and updates the progress bar for a running event
     * @returns {home} Returns this module for chaining
     */
    updateGenerationProgress: function() {
        var runningEvent = $(".running-event");
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "/Home/readGenerationStatusFile",
            global: false
        }).done(function(data) {
            runningEvent.css("width", data + "%").attr("aria-valuenow", data);
            if (data === "100") {
                console.log(this);
                clearInterval(this.updateProgressInterval);
                $("span", runningEvent).text("Complete").parent().removeClass("running-event").parent().removeClass("active progress-striped");
            }
        }.bind(this));
        return this;
    }

};
```

My main goal is to clear the interval set inside of the `loadStatusLog()` function from the `updateGenerationProgress()` function. The `console.log()` statement inside of `loadStatusLog()` outputs the correct context (this object) but the `console.log()` statement inside of `updateGenerationProgress()` outputs Window as the context. Why is this? Is there something I'm missing about promises and context?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to set the context on the interval too

```
this.updateProgressInterval = 
    setInterval(this.updateGenerationProgress.bind(this), 1000);
```

Otherwise, the context there gets set to `window` (or the worker) in non-strict mode and to `undefined` in strict mode.

Comment: Wow, can't believe I overlooked that. Thank you so much! That solved everything.

Comment: @Aaron I'm glad I could help, personally I'd split the logic of getting stuff from the server from the logic of updating the DOM.